# No error reported in php code yet no data goes into the database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I have the following simple form

simple form

TEST RUN FORM

```
    <form method=post action='android.php'>
    firstname:<input type='text' name='firstname'/><br>
    secondname:<input type='text' name='secondname'/><br>
    email:<input type='text' name='email'/><br>
    password<input type='text' name='password'/><br>
    <input type=submit name='submit' value='chekiii'/><br>
    </form>
    </body>
```

the php file is the one below, but it doesn't input any data into the database and doesn't show an error...infact it echoes out the 'success' message after parsing past the error code.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("www.######.com","#####","######");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("android", $con);
if ($_POST[submit])
{
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO magic (firstname,secondname,email,password)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[secondname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]')");

if (mysql_query(!$sql,$con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "success";
mysql_close($con);}
?>
```

What error might i have?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried echoing the $sql query and then manually adding it to the database? That might give you an error you can work with. The one thing I notice is that you don't have quotes around your $_POST variables: i.e. use `$_POST['firstname']` in stead of `$_POST[firstname]`.

Oh, and please add some checks on the userinput before you go live with this form...

Answer (score 0):

this wont work

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO magic (firstname,secondname,email,password)
VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[secondname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]')");
```

use this

```
"INSERT INTO magic (firstname,secondname,email,password)
VALUES ('".$_POST['firstname']."','".$_POST['secondname']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['password']."')"
```

also change this :

```
if (mysql_query(!$sql,$con)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

to

```
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

you have errors all over your code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("www.######.com","#####","######");
if (!$con){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("android", $con);
if ($_POST['submit']){ //$_POST['submit'] NOT $_POST[submit]
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO magic (firstname,secondname,email,password)
    VALUES ('".$_POST['firstname']."','".$_POST['secondname']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['password']."')");

if (mysql_query(!$sql,$con)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "success";
mysql_close($con);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is when you are passing your $_POST variables into your query string.

First, you **need** to sanitize this data before throwing it into a query or you're open to SQL injection attacks.

Second, the fix the error, add `{` and `}` around your $_POST variables, so they can be evaluated in the double quoted string. You're also missing single quotes in your $_POST variable indeces.

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO magic (firstname,secondname,email,password)
  VALUES
  ('{$_POST['firstname']}','{$_POST['secondname']}','{$_POST['email']}','{$_POST['password']}')");
```

See php [variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) documentation for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

please, dont use deprecated code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(..... );
mysqli_select_db(...);
mysqli_query($con,...); 
and to every $_POST mysqli_real_escape_string($con,....);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the references to the database. With CPANEL installed by my host i hadn't realized there were **database naming prefixes** which i wasn''t aware of as a noob (still am) . Thanks everyone. Still learning.